# Gstreamer - rtph264pay command

Tags: udp, video-streaming, gstreamer, h.264, rtp

I need to figure out the mechanism behind rtph264pay command. I have retrieved its output, but I don't understand how to read it. Where is the beginning of a frame ?
If I replace filesink with udpsink, frames are sent over the network. How does udpsink determine where a frame begins and ends.

```
c:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin\gst-launch-1.0.exe filesrc location=%string:\=/% ^
    ! decodebin ! x264enc ^
    ! "video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, profile=(string)baseline" ^
    ! h264parse ^
    ! rtph264pay ^
    ! filesink ^
    location=video.txt
```

Comment: How about "x264enc"? What method you tried to in reading/receiving side?

Answer (score 0):

The `rtph264pay` element takes in H264 data as input and turns it into RTP packets. RTP is a standard format used to send many types of data over a network, including video. RTP is formally outlined in [RFC 3550](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550), and specific information on how it is used with H264 can be found in [RFC 6184](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6184).

> How does udpsink determine where a frame begins and ends.

`udpsink` doesn't need to know where frames begin and end, it simply sends the RTP packets created by `rtph264depay` over UDP. It doesn't have any special understanding of the RTP format. It is the receiver of that data that needs to understand RTP in order to depayload it and decode it.

Since RTP is a format designed to be sent over a network, it's somewhat unusual to save them to a file with `filesink`.